# Bad SSL Certificate for meta.wordpress.stackexchange.com on redirect

Tags: bug, status-declined

Visiting https://meta.wordpress.stackexchange.com redirects here, but not before Chrome gives a full page SSL invalid warning

Comment: As Mad Scientist [answered](https://wordpress.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4412/31369), the URL is wrong. And given there is no certificate for that domain (and never was), that's the expected behaviour. You will note that accessing the URL over http will redirect without a warning.

Answer (score 4):

The new URL is wordpress.meta.stackexchange.com since the switch to SSL. So that link is simply wrong, and the certificate error expected.

If that link is still active somewhere on the site, it should be edited to the new version.

Comment: There is a server with an invalid certificate doing the redirect though. It's not that I expected to find this site as is on that URL, it's that the redirecting server is sending that redirect HTTP header with an invalid SSL certificate. If the URL is wrong then I should be getting a DNS failure. Instead I'm seeing a server that redirects. The redirecting server is misconfigured

Comment: @TomJNowell You can find some more information in the comments on https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/294810/151385 .